# Bootstrap File Input Style

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to style a file input with a consistent style to Bootstrap, how I can accomplish that? Do I need a plugin or it is already built-in? I Checked Bootstrap components and didn't find it.

Comment: Here is good plugin. https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Bootstrap documentation (CSS) you have the example
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-example

Here is a link to customize a file input button
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/custom-file-input-styling-webkitblink/

Comment: I checked it a while ago, and the file input have no style. I need to style my file input in a consistent style to Bootstrap buttons.

Comment: In that case you should do on your own. Here you can see a way of do it http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/custom-file-input-styling-webkitblink/

Comment: Please edit your answer with the useful link you provided in you comment.

Answer (score 2):

bootstrap-filestyle is a owsome jquery plugin to style the the file input easily.

please check the demo

http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/